# How to get the width and height of the row on the tableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

Here i m getting width and height as 0   , how to find exact width and height of the row in the tableLayout

```
    tr.addView(txt, params);
    tr.addView(l, lay);


    tr1.addView(txt1, params);
    tr1.addView(l1, lay);

    tr2.addView(btn, params);
    tr2.addView(l2, lay);

    tr3.addView(txt2, params);
    tr3.addView(iV22, lay);

    tl.addView(tr);

    tl.addView(tr1);

    tl.addView(tr2);              
          int height = tr.getHeight();
          Log.d("Height", String.valueOf(height));
          int Width = tr.getWidth();
          Log.d("Width", String.valueOf(Width));
          setContentView(tl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get layout sizes only then activity is shown. Try to get button ib your activity and get sizes by button click.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
table.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout()
            {
                Log.d("", row.getWidth();

            }
        });
```

Comment: This works to get the Screen size / Global Layout , I need to get the row width and height. Thank you